# Как объединить 2+ метода преобразования текста

Tags: javascript, текст

Надо бы, чтобы одновременно пробелы превращались в `<br>`, и первая буква становилась заглавная.

```
$(this).html(s.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+s.substr(1).toLowerCase());
$(this).html(s.replace(/\s/g, "<br>"));
```

По одиночке работают. Если оба в функции - срабатывает только последний.

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/ywk85hpq/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вторым присвоением ты редактируешь не то что у тебя было в первой строке, а то что ты получил с функции.

```
s = s.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+s.substr(1).toLowerCase();
$(this).html(s.replace(/\s/g, "<br>"));
```

ну или просто в одну строку всё сделать

```
$(this).html(s.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+s.substr(1).toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "<br>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что строка не сохраняется, нужно либо сохранить результат в переменную и уже работать с ней дальше, либо сразу реплейсить через точку

```js
$(this)
  .html(
    (s.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+s.substr(1).toLowerCase())
    .replace(/\s/g, "<br>")
  );
```